# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command under Subprocess

Tags: python, jenkins, pip

I have some `virtualenv` under Jenkins CI which collect my package and running:

```
python setup.py test
```

the virtualenv has pip installed and i'm exporting the path `.my_env/Scripts` (the CI is under windows), At my setup.py i'm trying to call pip to install `pywin32` using `subprocess.call`, script output:

```
+ pip list
pip (7.0.3)
setuptools (17.1.1)
+ echo '######### starting test #########'
######### starting test #########
+ python setup.py test
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

You can see that `pip list` is working find then i'm calling the `setup.py test`

**setup.py**

```
...
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    bin_path = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'bin', 'pywin32-219.zip')
    subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', bin_path], shell=True)
...
```

Any idea why pip is recognised at the Jenkins shell but not at the `subprocess.call`?

Comment: Doing a subprocess call in `setup.py` seems rather unusual to me. If you really want to invoke pip manually in your `setup.py`, why not through `import pip` and `pip.main(["install", "mypackage"])`?  Yet this is probably still horrible advice. I wouldn't do that :D

Comment: It seems reasonable, any idea of a best practice for adding requirements by os? like at my case of installing pywin32 only if the sys is win32?

Comment: If the package is available on `pypi`, then you can use setuptools and collect dependencies in `setup_requires` during the execution of `setup.py` before invoking `setup`. If it's not on pypi, then things are getting difficult I guess.